# Python Help - issue with Flask

Tags: python

I have flask installed but when I try to run my app I just get the following ...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask.Lib import Flask, render_template
ImportError: cannot import name 'Flask' from 'flask.Lib' (unknown location)
```

Comment: `from flask import Flask, render_template`

Answer (score -1):

It's just

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
```

Not sure where you got `flask.Lib` from...

Comment: Sorry no idea why I had that but it's the same anyway ImportError: cannot import name 'Flask' from 'flask' (unknown location)

Comment: Then make sure you're running your code in the same interpreter and environment you've installed Flask into.